# No such module 'SocketIO'

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am using package manager to import `SocketIO` library in my swift project but it gives me this error:

> No Such Module

I have made changes in *package.resolved* as well but still I am getting this error and I don't find any dependencies in *Target Dependencies* under build phases it has 0 items.

I have made changes in *package.swift* to import this library.

I'm using Swift version 4.2 and Xcode above 10.0.

Here is my *Package.swift*:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "VV",
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift", .upToNextMinor(from: "13.0.0"))
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(name: "VV", dependencies: ["SocketIO"], path: "./Sources")
  ]
)
```

The *Package.resolved*:

```
{
  "object": {
    "pins": [
      {
        "package": "SocketIO",
        "repositoryURL": "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift",
        "state": {
          "branch": null,
          "revision": "b6a8984ce0b9926dd68421b6b6",
          "version": "13.0.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "package": "Starscream",
        "repositoryURL": "https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream",
        "state": {
          "branch": null,
          "revision": "ebdc260ea69c624b5cd15d3a49d6",
          "version": "3.0.6"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Which commands have you runs? I've tested it on my side and everything is working well.

Comment: And how do you import your socket.io module?

Comment: @YannickLoriot what commands you tried ? I tried everything i found on web

Comment: Have you done the `swift package update` and then the `swift package generate-xcodeproj`? Then the `swift build` still failing?

Comment: @YannickLoriot yes i did

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project `swift package clean`? Have you tried with a minimum project?

Comment: @YannickLoriot i did it with pod and its working fine Thanks!